# C#: Сравнить две Access базы и выявить изменения

Tags: c#, sql, .net, access

Есть старая версия базы и новая версия базы.
Изменения в новой базе могут быть абсолютно любыми:

1. Удалены N строк
2. Добавлены N строк
3. Добавлена таблица
4. Удалена таблица
5. Изменено значение колонки
   и т д.

Как наиболее быстро сравнить 2 базы?
Есть вариант выполнить полный перебор. Но не затянется ли он на долго?

Существуют ли готовые решения, которые я мог бы добавить в виде библиотеки в проект?

**UPD:**

Может все хитро загнать в DataTable и сравнить в памяти?

Comment: Ну для таблиц, при создании запросов, можно выбрать в качестве типа "Find Unmatched Query Wizard"(в русской версии - "Записи без подчиненных") - с его помощью довольно легко можно найти отличия между таблицами в двух базах.

Comment: Почему бы вам не воспользоваться готовым софтом для этого?

Comment: У меня служба при загрузке баз должна проверять изменения. Если существует такое решение, которое можно вызывать через C#, а оно само в свою очередь будет писать информацию, то напишите как называется это решение.

Comment: не забывайте ставить символ `@` с ником пользователя, что бы он получил оповещение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю на счет готового софта, но сделать такое можно через операции над множествами, с коими шарп умеет работать.

Вам потребуется лишь загружать нужные данные и переводить их в множетсва (в принципе можно и с обычными коллекциями работать, но время выполнения будет дольше) https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397727%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - ссылка на класс множеств. После этого нужно выполнять определенные действия, чтобы получить определенный результат:

- Чтобы узнать какие таблицы были удалены в новой базе - Отнять из множества таблиц старой базы множество новой
- Чтобы узнать, какие таблицы были добавлены - отнять из множества новой базы множество старой

Чтобы узнать изменения по столбцам, нужно получить множество столбцов таблицы. Чтобы получить изменения свойств столбцов (изменение типа, например), нужно загрузить множество свойств. Чтобы узнать изменение данных (строк), нужно загрузить в множества строки и тд.

Тут не все так сложно и долго, как может показаться на первый взгляд. А время работы программы будет зависеть от размера базы.

**UPD:**

Прежде чем запускать, прочитайте до конца

Вот окошко... Скопируйте себе его содержимое в новое окно.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding T1}" CanUserReorderColumns="False"/>
            <Button Content="Скопировать" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <DataGrid Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding T2}" CanUserReorderColumns="False"/>
            <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding T3}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Вот код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DataTable _t1;
        DataTable _t2;
        DataTable _t3;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            _t1 = new DataTable();
            _t2 = new DataTable();
            _t3 = new DataTable();
            _t1.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int)).AutoIncrement = true;
            _t1.Columns.Add("field1", typeof(string));
            _t1.Columns.Add("field2", typeof(string));
            _t1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { _t1.Columns[0] };
            _t2 = _t1.Clone();
            _t3.Columns.Add("PK", typeof(string));
            _t3.Columns.Add("Action", typeof(string));
            T1 = _t1.DefaultView;
            T2 = _t2.DefaultView;
            T3 = _t3.DefaultView;
            _t1.RowChanged += _t1_RowChanged;
            _t1.RowDeleted += _t1_RowChanged;
            _t2.RowChanged += _t1_RowChanged;
            _t2.RowDeleted += _t1_RowChanged;
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void _t1_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            FindingChanges();
        }

        void FindingChanges()
        {
            _t3.Rows.Clear();
            var hs1 = new HashSet<string>();
            var hs2 = new HashSet<string>();

            // СТРОКИ ДОЛЖНЫ СРАВНИВАТЬСЯ ПО СОВОКУПНОСТИ PRIMARY KEY, ПОЭТОМУ ПОЛУЧАЕМ МАССИВ ВИДА "pk1;pk2...". В НАШЕМ СЛУЧАЕ ПРОСТО "pk"
            foreach (DataRow row in _t1.Rows)
                hs1.Add(GetPrimaryKeyToString(row));
            foreach (DataRow row in _t2.Rows)
                hs2.Add(GetPrimaryKeyToString(row));

            var hsDel = new HashSet<string>(hs1.Where(e => true));
            var hsAdd = new HashSet<string>(hs2.Where(e => true));

            // ВОТ ТУТ ВЫЧИТАНИЕ
            hsDel.ExceptWith(hs2);
            hsAdd.ExceptWith(hs1);

            foreach (var item in hsAdd)
                _t3.Rows.Add(item, "Added");
            foreach (var item in hsDel)
                _t3.Rows.Add(item, "Deleted");
        }

        // ЭТО ФУНКЦИЯ, КОТОРАЯ ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ПЕРВИЧНОГО КЛЮЧА В ВИДЕ СТРОКИ
        string GetPrimaryKeyToString(DataRow row)
        {
            return string.Join(";", row.Table.PrimaryKey.Select(col => Convert.ToString(row[col])));
        }

        public DataView T1 { get; set; }
        public DataView T2 { get; set; }

        public DataView T3 { get; set; }

        void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CopyTable();
        }
        void CopyTable()
        {
            _t2.Rows.Clear();
            foreach(DataRow row in _t1.Rows)
            {
                var newRow = _t2.NewRow();
                var i = 0;
                foreach (var col in row.ItemArray)
                    newRow[i++] = col;
                _t2.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

отсюда нужны все методы. Ну и содержимое конструктора в том виде, в котором оно представлено.

Не обращать внимание на код инициализации таблиц. Вас интересует метод `FindingChanges()`.

Для того, чтобы сравнить таблицу построчно, нужны значения первичных ключей (иначе как еще понять, что та или иная строка была добавлена или удалена).

Данный код проверят только на удаление и добавление. Для проверки изменений следует сравнивать все совпадающие строки из обоих таблиц по всем параметрам. я не стал тут этого делать.

Запускаем форму. Там есть по порядку:

Таблица, кнопка "скопировать", Таблица, Таблица

Первая таблица - это старая версия таблицы

Кнопка копирует все содержимое первой таблицы во вторую

Вторая таблица - это новая таблица

Третья таблица выводит результаты изменений

То есть после того как вы заполните первую таблицу и нажмете скопировать, третья таблица будет пустой. Теперь начинаете чего то делать с таблицами 1 и 2. Например, если удалить строку из таблицы 1, то это будет означать, что в новой таблице была добавлена строка (потому что в старой этой строки нет). Если удалить другую строку из таблицы 2, то это будет означать, что в новой таблице была удалена строка. Ну короче разберетесь.

Код, наверное, не красивый, но на мой взгляд понятный.

Comment: Я создаю 2 DataTable, наполняю их данными. Затем делаю HashSet<DataRows> hs=dt.rows ? Можно примерчик по одному из пунктов, что бы иметь шаблон взаимодействия?

Comment: @iluxa1810, нет, наполнять надо чем то вроде HashSet<string> , где будут содержаться первичные ключи (или производные от них, если столбцов первичного ключа несколько). Я сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: А по производительности я выиграю если буду производить сравнение в памяти, а не запросами к 2 ум Access бд ?

Comment: @iluxa1810 определенно нет.

Comment: @iluxa1810, хотя не знаю. 2 разные базы. Запросы придется делать к двум базам, а не к двум таблицам одной базы. В случае с SQL server, возможно, это бы не было проблемой, потому что вы бы обошлись одним подключением и могли бы делать комбинированные запросы к двум разным базам на одном сервере. А так... Спорно в общем

Comment: @iluxa1810, а вы случайно не в МТУСИ учитесь? ))

Comment: не, в МИФИ. А что?